# Bootstrap select not working in firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, select

So, I have to put a select box with Bootstrap. The thing is, it looks great in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox 25.0.1 looks AWFUL.

Is anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the awfulness and some code that used to generate it?

Comment: Yes - according to what we can tell, it looks totally great in firefox :)